# Converting xy coordinates to theta without discontinutities

Tags: python, python-3.x, coordinate-system

This one is, or rather, should be, fairly simple. I have a list of tuples of XY positions, and am trying to pull out angles relative to the origin from it. However, unlike `atan2` / friends, I want it to be continuous, in other words *not* wrapping. I know (and am assuming) that the differences between successive XY coordinates are small, and that there is a minimum radius. (In other words, it should pick the multiple of \$2\pi\$ that makes the difference between the previous angle and the current angle the smallest.)

Currently, this is the relevant snippet:

```
thetas = [math.atan2(coords[0][1], coords[0][0])]
prev = thetas[0]
for index in range(1, len(coords)):
    coord = coords[index]
    theta = math.atan2(coord[1], coord[0]) + (prev // (2*math.pi)) * (2 * math.pi)
    while theta - prev > math.pi:
        theta -= 2*math.pi
    while prev - theta > math.pi:
        theta += 2*math.pi
    assert abs(theta - prev) < math.pi/2
    thetas.append(theta)
    prev = theta
```

However, it's slow, and I doubt it's Pythonic. It's also doing a lot of "magic", for lack of a better word. Any suggestions for improvement?

Line profiler results [here](http://pastebin.com/a1vsEUi1).

Comment: a simple question is why does it need to be continuous?

Comment: How can you assert that `abs(theta - prev) < math.pi/2`? Is there some guarantee that the XY coordinates are clustered in some quadrant?

Comment: Quote: "I know (and am assuming) that the differences between successive XY coordinates are small." I should have specified that I know that there is a minimum radius as well.

Comment: @ratchetfreak, For plotting purposes, mainly. It's far easier to read a graph of something versus theta when theta doesn't wrap.

Answer (score 1):

- `for index in range()` is almost always wrong. Consider

  ```
  prev = coords[0]
  for coord in coords[1:]:
      theta = ...
      prev = coord
  ```
- Instead of computing `theta` directly, compute `delta` - this way you may actually take an advantage of small differences:

  ```
  prev = (1, 0)    # Initial vector is along the X axis
  theta = 0.0
  for coord in coords[]:
      delta = angle_between(coord, prev)
      theta += delta
      prev = coord
  ```

  Computing `delta` is simply an application of a cross-product formula:

  ```
  def angle_between(curr, prev):
      return asin(cross_product(curr, prev) / (norm(curr) / norm(prev))
  ```

Comment: Three problems with this. First off, that `angle-between` function doesn't make sense as written. (I'm working in 2D, for one thing, and for another arcsine isn't defined for vectors.) Secondly, that will end up with compounding rounding errors. Third, that method of indexing (`coords[1:]`) will make a temporary copy of the entire array. That's not exactly optimal for performance. Is there no good way to avoid that copy?